# How to make two containers connectable in AWS ECS Fargate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-ecs, aws-fargate

I have two containers added to a task definition

1. Node Container:

   ```
   name :nodeAPI
   port :exposed 5001
   mongoconnection string in the env variable : mongodb://mongo  [name of mongo container]
   ```
2. Mongo container:

   ```
   name :mongo
   port :exposed 27017
   ```

The node container is not able to connect to Mongo when I run this task. I am using Fargate and network as awsvpc.

1. How do I fix this?
2. How do I make it work running them from separate task definitions?

Comment: Just to clarify, are both containers in the same task definition? If so, you should be able to access the mongo container over localhost.

Comment: Since you are using awsvpc mode, you could try using service discovery provided part of Route 53 to find each other services.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ecs-service-discovery/

Comment: Roy ,okay I will try that  . I am just new to AWS , I should put the database in as a separate service right  ?   how do I connect if they are in separate services ?

Answer (score 2):

As every task in Fargate gets it own ENI, therefore correct way to communicate between containers in same task definition is calling local loopback `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`.

For example:

First Container will be able to communicate to second container using `127.0.0.1:<port of second container>` as address and second container can communicate to First container using `127.0.0.1:<port of first container>`

This is very well explained in AWS Blog: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/task-networking-in-aws-fargate/

Answer (score 0):

there's a security-group configuration when you running the task check whether those are open

[fargate security groep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jkz9y.png)

fargate acts like a ec2 onlything is you can use a docker image 
so you have to do normal ec2 configs

Answer (score 0):

If both containers are defined within the same "Task Definition" than they are able to communicate using "localhost".

In your example your NodeJs app will talk with mongo `localhost:27017`